# Nextjs switch body background color

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a button to change the background in Nextjs. Why this doesn't work?

`_app.js`

```
import '../styles/global.css'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useState } from 'react'


export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <style jsx global>{`
        ${ isDark ? 'body {background: darkslategray;}' : 'body {background: antiquewhite;}' }
      `}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure the internal implementation of `styled-jsx` but apparently this works:

```
<style jsx global>{`
  body {
    background: ${isDark ? "darkslategray" : "antiquewhite"};
  }
`}</style>
```

See [docs](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#via-interpolated-dynamic-props)

It is reasonable to think that your code could work as well so you may file an issue to [styled-jsx](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, your solution works. I don't understand why the other way doesn't. Do you know if there is a better approach to switch global themes? That was my original goal. I suppose that importing a global.css and adding or removing from component `className` is better but I  don't know how to make it work, or if it's rigth.